# WPF MVVM : Bind a command which is on a ViewModel in a Child ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Im using WPF with MVVM design-patern, and I need to bind a command which is of a ItemsSource binding parent :
View :

```
<Window x:Class="TaskSupervisor.MainWindow"
        ...
        ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:TacheGroupeViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView x:Name="TachesTree" ItemsSource="{Binding TachesGroupes.GroupesConfig}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Value.Tasks}">
                    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                              <CheckBox x:Name="InProgress" 
                                          IsChecked="{Binding ModifInProgress}">
                                </CheckBox>

                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    ...
                                </StackPanel>

                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    ...
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value.DisplayGroupe, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewModel :

```
class TacheGroupeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    public Model.TachesGroupes TachesGroupes { get; set; }

    public TacheGroupeViewModel() {
        this.TachesGroupes = new Model.TachesGroupes();
        // return a  Dictionary<string, CustomClass> Object
       // CustomClass => Contain some field and a List Of custom class
    }

    private ICommand _cmdEnCoursDeTraitement;
    public ICommand CmdEnCoursDeTraitement {
        get {
            return _cmdEnCoursDeTraitement ?? ( _cmdEnCoursDeTraitement = new RelayCommand(x => {Test(); }) );
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    public void Test() {
        var test = "xD";
    }
}
```

I want to make a bind on my Checkbox object : How can I do this while the Items source of the HierarchicalDataTemplate is set to "Tasks" I can only binding on my "Tasks" filds.
How can get the parent of the ItemSource ?

Comment: You would use a relativesource binding. I'm not clear where modifinprogress would be. If it's in the treeviewitem which is one level up then Binding  DataContext.YouProperty,  relativesource ancestortype treeviewitem and ancestorlevel 2. If it's in the window viewmodel then relativesource would be treeview ( which will presumably have same datacontext as window ).

Comment: The other option is to add a reference to the parent item on `TacheGroupeViewModel` and navigate through that for the binding.

Comment: Maybe I doing it wrong, this is my 1st real MVVM app, maybe there is a deeper problem with the way I do that

Comment: Where is the command?  I don't see if in the XAML.

Comment: There is no here cause the binding is wrong.
But if I would bind a command on the checkbox, how can I get my ViewModel Icommand ?

Comment: It looks like your view-model is what the `Window` is bound to.  Just name the `Window` element, and specify `ElementName` as part of your binding against the `DataContext`. So `<CheckBox Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.CmdEnCoursDeTraitement, ElementName=TheWindowName}" />`.

Comment: You've still not explained where the command will be. Or where you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

instead of finding the right parent and view model...I had a Forward pattern mainly for context menu...

All my view model have this command

```
private ICommand forwardCommand;
    public ICommand ForwardCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (forwardCommand == null)
                forwardCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(
                    delegate(string param)
                    {
                        Messenger.Default.Send<CommandContext>(GetForwardCommandContext(param),
                            ViewModelBaseMessages.ContextCommand );
                    },
                    delegate(string param)
                    {
                        return CanForwardCommand(param);
                    });
            return forwardCommand;
        }
    }
```

it is then forwarded to the view model that have registered to a forward_message

```
Messenger.Default.Register<CommandContext>(this, ViewModelBaseMessages.ContextCommand,
            (CommandContext o) =>
            {
                ExecuteDistantCommand( o );
            } );
```

you can find this code in my project on [github](https://github.com/TheCamel/CBR)
please, use a mvvm nuget like mvvmlight and do not invent the wheel...;-)